# How do I commit my IntelliJ IDEA Global Library configuration into source code control?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 running on a number of machines, all with identical paths for the project and modules but different local user names.  The .idea directory gets committed to the git repo.  When I make changes to my Global Libraries those are not reflected on the other machines because that info is in

C:\Users\user\.IdeaIC13\config\options\applicationLibraries.xml

I want changes to Global Library settings to be required only once and applied everywhere.

Should I tell IDEA to look for applicationLibraries.xml under the .idea directory instead of in the local user's directory which is not under version control?  how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution was to go into Project Structure, right click on each Global Library and choose "Copy To Project Libraries..." then remove the original from Global Libraries.  Then in each project remove the old global library and add the newly created project library.  This way library data is stored in the .idea dir and not the user's dir.

Comment: Grr... I assumed global meant shared. :-(

Comment: This is a workaround without explaining why a workaround would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

The `applicationLibraries.xml` file, among others, are stored in a platform-dependent folder in the repo, for example in `_linux` or `_windows`. If this is your problem, read on.

For things like keymaps this is wanted because things work differently after all, but for libraries which either only contain jars, or contain binaries (dll/so) for all platforms, this is unwanted.

- On the PC with the global libraries (assuming linux for now):
- Copy the file from `config/settingsRepository/repository/_linux` to `_windows`,
- Execute `git add _windows/applicationLibraries.xml` from the command line,
- Restart IntelliJ,
- Merge repo (not Overwrite remote)

This solved it for me, and now I have global libraries on all my computers, and not just my linux computers.